# Loop robocopy through network drives

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

EDIT: If anyone cares here's a working version of my original code.
Only by removing  the space in the "Drive C" path I could get robocopy to take the /r:1 /w:1 options.
I'm aware now, is in no way the best way to do it.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "count=1"
set "local=c:\cmd_Scripts\"

:update
echo Connecting to machine !count!.
if exist "\\10.3.71.6!count!\Disk_C\cmd_Scripts\" (
    robocopy %local% \\10.3.71.6!count!\Disk_C\cmd_Scripts\ /r:1 /w:1
    echo Machine !count! DONE.
    echo.
    set /a count+=1
    if /i !count! LEQ 9 goto update
) else (
    echo MAchine !count! not available.
    echo.
    set /a count+=1
    if /i !count! LEQ 9 goto update
)
```

So again I'm stuck.
If the network drive is available works fine, but if not available should go to the next IP.
Also I don't understand why need to open "%target% but can't close ". And because of this can't pass any options like /r:1 /:w1

```
@echo off
set count=1
set "local=c:\cmd_Scripts\"
set "target=\\10.3.71.6%count%\Disk C\cmd_Scripts\"

:update
if exist %target% (
    set "target=\\10.3.71.6%count%\Disk C\cmd_Scripts\"
    robocopy %local% "%target%
    set /a count+=1
    if /i %count% LEQ 9 goto update
) else (
    set /a count+=1
    if /i %count% LEQ 9 goto update
)   
pause
```

Thanks
Alex

Comment: if target exists, you set it again? Why?

Comment: I guess... I got confused because of the %count%,  var inside var ...

Comment: ok, I see what you tried to do there, let me review quick.

Comment: Take a look at [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Comment: Appreciate everybody help. But to help me understand, can I get an explanation why my code is not working and that weird thing with "%target% ?

Comment: Thanks  aschipf from my understanding of the delayed expansion is not need in this case.

Comment: @SirAleXbox In Compos version the delayed expansion is **not** needed. In your original batch you set and use a variable inside a (code block) and that's the classic reason **you have to enable and use delayed expansion enclosing `!variable!` names in exclamation marks.**

Comment: Thanks for the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably write it like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "DLocal=C:\cmd_Scripts"
Set "IPBase=\\10.3.71.6"

For /L %%A In (1 1 9) Do If Exist "%IPBase%%%A\Disk %DLocal::=%\" (
    RoboCopy "%DLocal%" "%IPBase%%%A\Disk %DLocal::=%" /<options>
)
Pause
```

**Edit**

What follows is effectively a repeat of my answer but with more similarity to your question code. It means that you can preset `%target%` and use it in your loop, without enabling delayed expansion.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "local=C:\cmd_Scripts"
Set "target=\\10.3.71.6%%A\Disk %local::=%"

For /L %%A In (1 1 9) Do (
    Echo %target%
    If Exist "%target%\" RoboCopy "%local%" "%target%" /<options>
)
Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe move away from the count and use `for /l` instead.

```
@echo off
set "local=c:\cmd_Scripts\"
for /l %%i in (1,1,9) do (
if exist "\\10.3.71.6%%i\Disk C\cmd_scripts\" robocopy "%local%" "\\10.3.71.6%%i\Disk C\cmd_scripts\"
)
```

if you really need to set the `target` variable:

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "local=c:\cmd_Scripts\"
for /l %%i in (1,1,9) do (
set "target=\\10.3.71.6%%i\Disk C\cmd_scripts\"
if exist "!target!" robocopy "!local!" "!target!"
)
```

From cmdline, do `for /?` to understand what it does, especially with the `/l` switch. but in short doing `(1,1,9)` means we count from `1`, in 1s to `9` and perform the parenthesized commands 9 times in this case.